# Code restart after end

Tags: javascript

How can I restart this code every 10-20 sec.I cant seem to figure it out!

This is the code. (I'm still new any help would be great.)

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary next-btn slide-transition ');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     items[i].click();
}
```

Comment: It's javascript. What is does is simple, it loops through all the items that are `btn-primary next-btn-slide-transition` and clicks them.

Comment: ok i understand that. Lets say the page refreshes after ever click how can i get the code to re enter in Console?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary next-btn slide-                      
  transition');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {      
  items[i].click();
  }
}, 10000);
```

It sets up your code as a function that is executed every 10000 millliseconds

Comment: Ok i had the ; in the wrong spot. And lets say the page refreshes after ever click how can i get the code to re enter in Console? Thanks Btw Serge

Comment: I don't get you. I were assuming this is a code in some `<script>` tag in your page. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct sorry new to the site. But once the page refreshes how can i get the code to reenter console then start again after ever refresh? thanks Serge.

Comment: if this code is in your page then it will be executed automatically within 10 seconds. If you need it to be executed the first time upon the page load, then place the code into named function and call the function. then use the same function in window.setInterval call

Answer (score 0):

You could Just refresh the Page too

```
Var x = 900000;

setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, x);
```

Every x millisecond

Careful though; you will lose the current JavaScript variables that didn't get posted to a database

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, if you want to execute code every refresh then below code will help you.

```
var timer;
function StartTimer() {
  timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary next-btn slide-                      
  transition');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {      
  items[i].click();
  }
},10000); 
}
StartTimer();
```